# How to generate spec with scaffold.Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a controller 'comments' and I want to test the Comments Controller. How can I generate scaffold comments_spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rails g rspec:scaffold comment
```